# Unitialized variable in for loop in JavaScript - what is the semantics of that?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-maps-api-3

In the [Google API 3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) I saw the following code, which made me wonder a little bit.

```
...
for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
}
...
```

In the `for` loop just after the initialization of the loop variable is put another variable `marker` without assignment.

**I wonder what the semantics of that is. Can someone explain?**

To be honest, I don't even know how to search for that, because I don't know how to call that. (I get search results explaining loops in general, but not this specific case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `marker` is declared, and its initial value is `undefined`.

Immediately thereafter, the variable is the target of an assignment expression in the `for` loop test expression.

If the loop block is executed, then that means `marker` will have some "truthy" value in the body of the block. After the loop, `marker` will have some "falsy" value.

In all cases, `var` inside a `for` loop header is treated the same way as a plain `var` statement. The loop in your question is exactly equivalent to

```
var i, marker;
for (i = 0; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

Note that `var` declarations — including those in `for` loop headers — are interpreted as if the declaration (*just* the declaration, separate from any initialization expression) were placed at the very beginning of the enclosing scope.

Comment: Basically, this loop will keep iterating as long as `markers[i]` is truthy, right? So it will iterate over all markers in `markers`.

Comment: @Cerbrus not necessarily. If `markers` were `[{}, null, {}]` then the iteration would stop when `i` is `1`, and the last object would be skipped.

Comment: @Cerbrus well maybe they're confident that there won't be holes in the array (which doesn't seem too crazy to me). I mean, in *general* there's no guarantee, but for some specific piece of code (like, when the array came from a `querySelectorAll()` call) it may be perfectly safe.

Comment: Possibly, then the advantage would be not to need a separate `var marker = markers[i]` _and_ a `i < markers.length`, so shorter code...